Docker image is not running in docker desktop
Context: The use case is creating an docker image of a asp.net mvc application and run it within Dcoker Desktop as local container. The Visual Studio Code is the IDE. The app is published by folloiwng command
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./bin/Publish

Once the the publication is done then the docker image was created through following command
docker build -t testapp 

The testapp is visible as one of the image in docker by executing the following command
docker images

The problem statement: Though the image is created but not able to run the image in the container by executing the following command
docker run -d -p 80:8080 testapp

Cannot see the running containers after executing the follwing command
docker ps

It seems the container i.e. docker desktop is not able to run the image.
Can anyone put some light on getting the root cause of the issue?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-netcore

Just a guess since you're saying asp.net instead of .net core, are you building a windows container and trying to run it when docker is set to run linux containers?  Are you getting an error message?   Can you try running with '-it' and see what it says?   Could it be that you can't allocate port 80?

Use docker ps -a, to also see containers that have shut down already. You should be able to retrieve the logs (which is just captured stdout/stderr) from that container to continue with your research. Alternatively, don't detach from the started container. BTW: It would help if you added the full output those commands above generate and describe what you would have expected to see. As it stands, we only have your interpretation of what you saw, which may well be flawed!
